# Coding stored procedure for search screen with multiple, optional criteria

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, option-type

I've got a search screen on which the user can specify any combination of first name, last name, semester, or course. I'm not sure how to optimally code the SQL Server 2005 stored procedure to handle these potentially optional parameters. What's the most efficient way? Separate procedures for each combination? Taking the items in as nullable parms and building dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution is to utilize sp_execute_sql. For example:

```
--BEGIN SQL
declare @sql nvarchar(4000)

set @sql = 
'select * from weblogs.dbo.vwlogs 
where Log_time between @BeginDate and @EndDate'
+ case when @UserName is null then '' else 'and client_user = @UserName' end

sp_execute_sql
@sql
, @params = '@UserName varchar(50)'
, @UserName = @UserName
--END SQL
```

As muerte mentioned, this will have a performance benefit versus exec()'ing a similar statement.

Comment: How would this change if I had the following parameters:
1. Lastname (LIKE operator)
2. Course (no LIKE)
3. Section (no LIKE)
With all intact, it would be:
SELECT * FROM courseEnrollment where Lastname like 'Bob%' and course='100' and section='001'

Comment: Alter the "client_user = @UserName" portion to reflect what actual condition you want added to your query.

Answer (score 7):

I'd set each parameter to optional (default value being null)

and then handle it in the *WHERE*....

```
FirstName=ISNULL(@FirstName,FirstName)
AND
LastName=ISNULL(@LastName,LastName)
AND
SemesterID=ISNULL(@SemesterID,SemesterID)
```

That'll handle only first name, only last name, all three, etc., etc.

It's also a lot more pretty/manageable/robust than building the SQL string dynamically and executing that.

Comment: I agree, it is more readable, but the plan will be cached just for the first pattern, so if performance is issue, executing dynamic sql might be better solution.

Comment: + 1 I would do the same, but use the (@Paremeter is null or Column = @Paremeter) syntax

Comment: Until you start going to the direction of parameters determining the joins you use, this method is still fairly good on performance, @muerte  And, as a general rule, performance is expendable -- maintainability/readability isn't ;)

Comment: You might try optimizing a bit and getting the NULL out of the where clause. From what I understand (and this might be dated information), the MS SQL Query plan processor never reuses a cached query plan when a NULL parameter appears in a where clause.

Comment: You probably don't want this if your columns are nullable.  As soon as the user doesn't provide a search term for one of these, any records that have a null value would be excluded.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with **sp_executesql** because the plan will be cached just for the first pattern, or the first set of conditions.

Take a look at this [TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx):

*sp_executesql can be used instead of stored procedures to execute a Transact-SQL statement many times when the change in parameter values to the statement is the only variation. Because the Transact-SQL statement itself remains constant and only the parameter values change, the SQL Server query optimizer is likely to reuse the execution plan it generates for the first execution.*

Comment: If you use sp_executesql, you need to make sure that you do not introduce any SQL injection problems.

Comment: So your answer is "dynamic sql" then.

Comment: Not necessarily - the question was for the stored procedure solution, and there might be some additional logic before sp_executesql. Bottom line, the real answer is that one should try to avoid checking for NULL values for each parameter, at least for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Was just posting the same concept as Kevin Fairchild, that is how we typically handle it.

You could do dynamic sql in your code to create the statement as required but if so you need to watch for sql injection.

Answer (score 0):

As muerte points out, the plan will be cached for the first set of parameters. This can lead to bad performance when its run each subsequent time using alternate parameters. To resolve that use the WITH RECOMPILE option on the procedure.